# Exception occurred during processing request: There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [enter-goal] associated with context path

Tags: struts2, action, action-mapping

I am trying to create a link from one page to another page. My main page is: enter-protein.jsp and i want to create a link in this page which will forward to another page when anybody will click the link. I already created the link but it does not properly forwarded to that page and an error is coming. I am getting the following error to create an application:

```
Sep 01, 2013 7:21:00 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger error
SEVERE: Exception occurred during processing request: There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [enter-goal] associated with context path [/ExampleTracker].
There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [enter-goal] associated with context path [/ExampleTracker]. - [unknown location]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy.prepare(DefaultActionProxy.java:185)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.prepare(StrutsActionProxy.java:63)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(StrutsActionProxyFactory.java:39)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(DefaultActionProxyFactory.java:58)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:553)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

My codes are the followings:

enter-protein.java

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
 <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="<s:url action="enter-goal" />"> Edit Goal</a>

</body>
</html>
```

enter-goal.jsp file is:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

 <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Goal format page</title>
</head>
<body>

    <s:form>
        <h1>Goal amount:</h1>
        <s:textfield name="goal"/>
        <s:submit value="Save" />
    </s:form>

</body>
</html>
```

Can you please help me where I have to change so that the error will be gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the s:url tag.

```
<a href="<s:url action="enter-goal" />"> Edit Goal</a>
```

The server-side tag tells Struts to return a URL to an action (controller in MVC terminology) named 'enter-goal'.  Actions are defined in the struts configuration file (or maybe annotations, not sure?).

To link to the JSP, just point to the JSP directly.  No need for a server-side tag:

```
<a href="enter-goal.jsp"> Edit Goal</a>
```

Comment: pointing directly to that it solves the linking problem. But if i try to access that page just like the url "http://localhost:8080/ExampleTracker/enter-goal" that is not working. it is mentionable, i use struts.xml file to configure.

Comment: You forgot the .jsp extension.

Comment: Thanks. It's working now. But is there any way to use the code <a href="<s:url action="enter-goal" />"> Edit Goal</a>. Actually, I already created that action file EnterGoal.java and now i need need to point that java file to get the default value form the java file of that text file in enter-goal.jsp file.

Comment: You need to make the EnterGoal action return a reference to the view for enter-goal.jsp.  Read up on the Struts configuration and views.

Comment: Can you please look into the code https://sites.google.com/site/solutionofproblems007/problem. Actually, I faced some problems to do this. That link has all essential codes.

Comment: @Brandon The action doesn't return reference, it returns a result or response (following the servlet technology).